# How to hide fieldset using CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to hide one fieldset using CSS. There are other fieldsets using same CSS class, and I don't want to hide them.

This is how the specific filedset looks like;

```
<fieldset class="span6">
                <legend>Search by User Name</legend>
                <label>
                    User Name:
                    <input id="kusersearch" data-provide="typeahead" name="searchuser" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text">
                </label>

                <label>
                    Exact Name:
                    <input name="exactname" value="1" type="checkbox">
                </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to modify HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You could do that using `nth-child` selector as it consist of `same class` for all fieldsets below,

```css
.span6:nth-child(3){
  border:none;
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="span6">
                <legend>Search by User Name</legend>
                <label>
                    User Name:
                    <input id="kusersearch" data-provide="typeahead" name="searchuser" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text">
                </label>

                <label>
                    Exact Name:
                    <input name="exactname" value="1" type="checkbox">
                </label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="span6">
                <legend>Search by User Name</legend>
                <label>
                    User Name:
                    <input id="kusersearch" data-provide="typeahead" name="searchuser" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text">
                </label>

                <label>
                    Exact Name:
                    <input name="exactname" value="1" type="checkbox">
                </label>
</fieldset>


<fieldset class="span6">
                <legend>Search by User Name</legend>
                <label>
                    User Name:
                    <input id="kusersearch" data-provide="typeahead" name="searchuser" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text">
                </label>

                <label>
                    Exact Name:
                    <input name="exactname" value="1" type="checkbox">
                </label>
</fieldset>


<fieldset class="span6">
                <legend>Search by User Name</legend>
                <label>
                    User Name:
                    <input id="kusersearch" data-provide="typeahead" name="searchuser" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text">
                </label>

                <label>
                    Exact Name:
                    <input name="exactname" value="1" type="checkbox">
                </label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a id to that fieldset and hide it.

AN unique ID will differentiate it from other elements having the same class.

```css
#unique {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="unique" class="span6">
                <legend>Search by User Name</legend>
                <label>
                    User Name:
                    <input id="kusersearch" data-provide="typeahead" 
               name="searchuser" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text">
                </label>

                <label>
                    Exact Name:
                    <input name="exactname" value="1" type="checkbox">
                </label>
               </fieldset>
```

Check the snippet its hidden. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try This ! Just use **hidden** attribute with your desired **input**

```html
<fieldset class="span6">
  <legend>Search by User Name</legend>
  <label>
                    User Name:
                    <input id="kusersearch" data-provide="typeahead" name="searchuser" autocomplete="off" value="" type="text" hidden>
                </label>

  <label>
                    Exact Name:
                    <input name="exactname" value="1" type="checkbox">
                </label>
</fieldset>
```